# Jquery live validating form input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

**UPDATE** Sorry I should have asked how would I do this is Jquery and is there any benefit in doing so.

Thanks

I'm currently using this code which sends the characters a user enters in an input field to  a php script which checks a DB to see if an ID value is in use or contains any invalid characters.

It works fine, but I'm curious if I would be better doing it a different way.

```
<input type='text' name='id' id='id' onkeyup="id(this.value)" /><span id='id'></span>


function id(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  {
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("id").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        if (xmlhttp.responseText.indexOf("set") != -1) {
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
        }
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","go.php?val="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

go.php is passed the individual characters and checks what is being submitted and returns the live results using :

```
echo stripslashes($response);
```

So as the user types into the text box there input is checked as they type. Is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: i dont see any jquery here

Comment: Curently, you use pure JavaScript to validate data from the server...
I hope you check again your inputs in server side, its the basics.
So, if you want to check it in the client side, you should use JS or jQuery to validate it (with pattern or custom functions), do not send it to the server, you will slow down your app.

Comment: As @Loenix said, too much of ajax call will slow down your application. try to minimize it, via - pattern matching(regex), min number of character constraint and by checking if the user has stopped typing (by watching time elapsed between keypress), i.e., say if the time between two key press is more then 2 sec/ the user is idele for 2 sec after a keypress, then make an ajax call.

Comment: Sorry I should have asked how do I do this in Jquery and will that be any better ! sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Asking if X is “better” than Y also makes little sense until you define your _criteria_ for what is to be considered “better” first. Using jQuery means embedding another script on the one hand, on the other it takes care of all browser inconsistencies for you and requires you to write less code yourself, and also to structure it a little nicer …

Comment: @CBroe - thanks can you point me in the right direction to do this is Jquery ?  Thanks

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/, http://api.jquery.com/